# How to center a UIMapView in the middle of a MKOverlay

Tags: iphone, ios, mkoverlay, mkmapview

I am using the following code (based on the Apple WWDC 2010 TileMap example) to load an UIMapView with a MKOverlay image (this could is in the viewDidLoad method):

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
TileOverlay *overlay = [[TileOverlay alloc] initWithTileDirectory:tileDirectory];
[map addOverlay:overlay];
```

Next I was to center the UIMapView map in the center of this overlay. At the moment I am doing this my hard-coding the latitude and longitude as follows:

```
double myLatitude = ...;
double myLongitude = ...;
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:myLatitude longitude:myLongitude];
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 4000, 4000);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [map regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[map setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

This works fine. I have tried to calculate the center of the overlay as follows:

```
double x, y;

x = MKMapRectGetMidX([overlay boundingMapRect]);
y = MKMapRectGetMidY([overlay boundingMapRect]);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(x, y));

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 4000, 4000);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [map regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[map setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

But this does not work. The MKCoordinateForMapPoint returns a latitude/longitude outside the overlay. I don't understand why.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you modified the boundingMapRect calculation in the sample code?  The centering code looks ok though the adjustedRegion calc is unnecessary (setRegion will do regionThatFits).  I get 37.718590,-122.343750.  What coordinate do you get?

Comment: That is what I get also...while that coordinate is inside the overlay it is not in the center.